# View updating ViewModel properties at startup

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Slider` control with minimum value higher than 0.  The `int` type property in the VM that the slider's bound to therefore has a initial value outside of slider value range.  How can I get the slider to update the VM property with its miminum value at application startup?  Currently it's only updating once the operator uses the slider.

```
<Slider Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Minimum="2" Maximum="100"
        AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPrecision="0"
        Value="{Binding Path=Controller.MotorModel.SelectedMovementSpeed}" />
```

EDIT:

My initial assumption that the View should define the operator's limits was wrong.  As [FCin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47429434/6839733) wrote, the View should only display values, while the logic should be in the ViewModel.  Here's my updated XAML:

```
<Slider Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPrecision="0"
        Minimum="{Binding Path=Controller.MotorModel.MinimumMovementSpeed}" 
        Maximum="{Binding Path=Controller.MotorModel.MaximumMovementSpeed}"
        Value="{Binding Path=Controller.MotorModel.SelectedMovementSpeed, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Set your minimum inside your code, not in the view.

Comment: Since there is no `BindingMode.UpdateSourceButThenTwoWay` you'll have to solve this a different way. Initial values of your ViewModel shouldn't come from your View anyways.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, I could set the initial property value in the VM using a constant and have the `Minimum` value bind to the constant to avoid setting it two times. 
 But isn't the idea that the View is setting the operators limits?  This just smacks of being anti-MVVM, doesn't it..?

Comment: @Oystein Quite the opposite. The view model should set the limits.

Comment: @Oystein To be honest that's something I'd set in the ViewModel. Your logic needs to know the limits to in my opinion.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer View only displays values to the user. It should have no logic at all. Your ViewModel should validate the input and check if it doesn't go outside boundries.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the MVVM canon update. :-)  @FCin, can you write it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `Minimum` value inside your ViewModel, not in the View. Views in MVVM should not contain any logic. They only display properties to a user. ViewModels should validate user's input based on bounded properties and methods.